# libGDX HTML5 Project Builds Differently on Different Machine

Tags: java, html, browser, gradle, libgdx

This is a strange one! On my old desktop, I was able to build and run my libGDX project for HTML5 using the gradlew html:dist gradle command.

I uploaded the files to my site and everything worked well.

But on my laptop I synced the project via GitHub to Android Studio, ran the same command and it appears that the default ApplicationListener runs instead of my own custom one.

The only thing that appears is a red rectangle: http://johnathongoss.com/jaggybattles/

The desktop and android versions run and build fine on my laptop.

I'm using Android Studio and the latest version of libGDX.

Here is some code:

```
public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication {

    @Override
    public ApplicationListener createApplicationListener() {
            return  new MyGame();
    }

    @Override
    public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {

            GwtApplicationConfiguration cfg = new GwtApplicationConfiguration(1280, 720);               

            return cfg;
    }

}

//MyGame Class (Doesn't seem to get this far?)

@Override
public void create() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
    setScreen(new LoadingScreen(this)); //Loads the assets and sets Main Menu Screen

}
```

I've had this problem before but it was because I didn't change the createApplicationListener() method to return my own custom ApplicationListener. Now it seems to return the right one, I really don't know what could be causing this.

I should point out I can't access my desktop computer anymore due to relocating.

Any advice would be gratefully received!

Edit: Loading Class

https://gist.github.com/jaggygames/79b1bd821f4203aadecfe5e8ba925150

Assets Class:
https://gist.github.com/jaggygames/5b863f1692b0974b769d5694b5a3334f

MyDistance Font Class
https://gist.github.com/ea7b5965488cd5672e9e7c20917df9a1

Comment: Its very difficult find/guess problem by given info, can you share your github repo or more code from "LoadingScreen" class.

Comment: I added some classes to my original post :)

Comment: I guess problem is: Not clearing colors in render loop, add this 2 lines at top of your render loop and try:

`Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Comment: I tried and I get the same result! I'm concerned that the resolution isn't the specified one in the 

    GwtApplicationConfiguration cfg = new GwtApplicationConfiguration(1280, 720);

This seems to imply that my ApplicationListener MyGame isn't being used for some reason.

Comment: ok, I just noticed, you are loading assets in render loop and setting screen in loop, you should never do that. load all assets in create method of MyGame. have a look at lifecycle of application:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle

Comment: Ah thank you for the heads up! I've moved loading assets into the create() method :) I'm still having the same problem though

Comment: So, I'm using gradlew html:superDev to try and troubleshoot. The first time I navigate to http://localhost:8080/html/, it gives what I've had before: a red screen. But when I use Dev Mode to recompile, everything runs as I expect. I just don't know what's changing in this new compiled mode!

Comment: sometimes browser stores cache for page, when you do superdev refresh, it loads new stuff but still original old stuff is there in cache. What I prefer to do: stop superdev mode by pressing Ctr+C or Cmd+C. In index.html file: `<script type="text/javascript" src="html/html.nocache.js?v=1.0"></script>` (notice "?v=1.0" at the end) add that text and increment it every time you want browser to refresh cache and relaunch again.
There is one more way to refresh cache, open developer console in browser and right click on refresh button and click on "Empty cache hard reload button"

Comment: go through wiki info about framework, it will help you: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki